# How do I convert Days into Hours?

Tags: vb.net

My code deletes files after a set amount of days. However I want to use hours for it to be more precise.

```
 Public Sub DeleteLastWriteTime(dirLWT As String)
    Try
        If Owner.PluginXML.LastWriteTime Then
            Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(dirLWT)
            For Each hkfile As IO.FileInfo In directory.GetFiles()
                If (Now - hkfile.LastWriteTime).Hours > Owner.PluginXML.DataAge Then hkfile.Delete()
            Next
            For Each folder As IO.DirectoryInfo In directory.GetDirectories()
                DeleteLastWriteTime(folder.FullName)
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log("Error DeleteLastWriteTime", LogLevel.Exception, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

How can i convert the given Days `Owner.PluginXML.DataAge` into hours? Is there a command that does that for me?

Comment: Multiply by 24?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know it was that simple :)

Comment: if you subtract from `DateTime.Now` a different DateTime, you get back a TimeSpan that contain the actual difference in hours, minutes etc. If you actually want to be precise.